# How to manage AVPlayer state in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swiftui, avfoundation, avkit

I have a list of URLs in SwiftUI. When I tap an item, I present a full screen video player. I have an `@EnvironmentObject` that handles some viewer options (for example, whether to show a timecode). I also have a toggle that shows and hides the timecode (I've only included the toggle in this example as the timecode view doesn't matter) but every time I change the toggle the view is created again, which re-sets the `AVPlayer`. This makes sense since I'm creating the player in the view's initialiser.

I thought about creating my own `ObserveredObject` class to contain an `AVPlayer` but I'm not sure how or where I'd initialise it since I need to give it a URL, which I only know from the initialiser of `CustomPlayerView`. I also thought about setting the player as an `@EnvironmentObject` but it seems weird to initialise something I might not need (if the user doesn't tap on a URL to start the player).

What is the correct way to create an `AVPlayer` to hand to AVKit's `VideoPlayer` please? Here's my example code:

```
class ViewerOptions: ObservableObject {
    @Published var showTimecode = false
}

struct CustomPlayerView: View {
    
    @EnvironmentObject var viewerOptions: ViewerOptions
    
    private let avPlayer: AVPlayer
    
    init(url: URL) {
        avPlayer = AVPlayer(url: url)
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            VideoPlayer(player: avPlayer)
            Toggle(isOn: $viewerOptions.showTimecode) { Text("Show Timecode") }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: For now I’m just using the system VideoPlayer - https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avkit/videoplayer

Comment: Not reproducible with provided code - CustomPlayerView is not recreated on toggle. Tested with Xcode 12.1 / iOS 14.1. Would you provide more context?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are a couple of approaches you can take here. You can try them out and see which one suits best for you.

Option 1: As you said you can wrap `avPlayer` in a new `ObserveredObject` class

```swift
class PlayerViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var avPlayer: AVPlayer? = nil
}

class ViewerOptions: ObservableObject {
    @Published var showTimecode = false
}


@main
struct DemoApp: App {
    var playerViewModel = PlayerViewModel()
    var viewerOptions = ViewerOptions()

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            CustomPlayerView(url: URL(string: "Your URL here")!)
                .environmentObject(playerViewModel)
                .environmentObject(viewerOptions)
        }
    }
}

struct CustomPlayerView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var viewerOptions: ViewerOptions
    @EnvironmentObject var playerViewModel: PlayerViewModel

    init(url: URL) {
        if playerViewModel.avPlayer == nil {
            playerViewModel.avPlayer = AVPlayer(url: url)
        } else {
            playerViewModel.avPlayer?.pause()
            playerViewModel.avPlayer?.replaceCurrentItem(with: AVPlayerItem(url: url))
        }
    }

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            VideoPlayer(player: playerViewModel.avPlayer)
            Toggle(isOn: $viewerOptions.showTimecode) { Text("Show Timecode") }
        }
    }
}
```

Option 2: You can add `avPlayer` to your already existing class `ViewerOptions` as an optional property and then initialise it when you need it

```swift
class ViewerOptions: ObservableObject {
    @Published var showTimecode = false
    @Published var avPlayer: AVPlayer? = nil
}

struct CustomPlayerView: View {

    @EnvironmentObject var viewerOptions: ViewerOptions

    init(url: URL) {
        if viewerOptions.avPlayer == nil {
            viewerOptions.avPlayer = AVPlayer(url: url)
        } else {
            viewerOptions.avPlayer?.pause()
            viewerOptions.avPlayer?.replaceCurrentItem(with: AVPlayerItem(url: url))
        }
    }

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            VideoPlayer(player: viewerOptions.avPlayer)
            Toggle(isOn: $viewerOptions.showTimecode) { Text("Show Timecode") }
        }
    }
}
```

Option 3: Make your `avPlayer` a state object this way its memory will be managed by the system and it will not re-set it and keep it alive for you until your view exists.

```swift
class ViewerOptions: ObservableObject {
    @Published var showTimecode = false
}

struct CustomPlayerView: View {

    @EnvironmentObject var viewerOptions: ViewerOptions
    @State private var avPlayer: AVPlayer

    init(url: URL) {
        _avPlayer = .init(wrappedValue: AVPlayer(url: url))
    }

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            VideoPlayer(player: avPlayer)
            Toggle(isOn: $viewerOptions.showTimecode) { Text("Show Timecode") }
        }
    }
}
```

Option 4: Create your `avPlayer` object when you need it and forget it (Not sure this is the best approach for you but if you do not need your player object to perform custom actions then you can use this option)

```swift
class ViewerOptions: ObservableObject {
    @Published var showTimecode = false
}

struct CustomPlayerView: View {

    @EnvironmentObject var viewerOptions: ViewerOptions
    private let url: URL

    init(url: URL) {
        self.url = url
    }

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            VideoPlayer(player: AVPlayer(url: url))
            Toggle(isOn: $viewerOptions.showTimecode) { Text("Show Timecode") }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That’s brilliant thank you - I’m away this week so can’t test it out but that’s great detail and looks like it’ll do exactly what I’m after. Thanks!

Comment: What if we want to use iOS 13? cus this answer is supported on iOS 14+