# AVPlayer refreshes when switching orientation (uses Firebase Firestore video link)

Tags: ios, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui, avplayer

I'm working on a video streaming app that uses firebase. I have a firestore database populated with video links and I can reference it on my app (firebasedb.video in the code below provides the matching video link). I'm using fullScreenCover and playing the video automatically. Testing the app on my own iPhone, I've stumbled on a problem where if I switch the orientation from portrait to landscape, the video refreshes and starts from the beginning. I suspect AVPlayer is making a new call to the database during the switch, so is there any way I can stop this from happening? Thank you and looking forward to your responses!

update: It would be really helpful if I can see a demo using init() for this code as I think that would solve the issue.

```
@State var firebasedb: movies
@ObservedObject var movies = getMoviesData()
@State private var isPlayed = false

var body: some View {
VStack {
   Button(action: {
         self.isPlayed.toggle()
   }) {
         Image(systemName: "play.circle")
              .font(.system(size: 50, weight: .light))                     
       }
   }
   .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $isPlayed){
                  VStack {
                      let avPlayer = AVPlayer(url: URL(string: firebasedb.video)!)
                      VideoPlayer(player: avPlayer)
                      .onAppear(){
                          avPlayer.play()
                      }
                      .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)

                  }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On switch orientation content of `fullScreenCover` is rebuild, but you create new instance of player inside, so `VideoPlayer` has reset.

To solve this move `avPlayer` creation somewhere outside

```
// make @State or init input
let avPlayer = AVPlayer(url: URL(string: firebasedb.video)!)

// ...

.fullScreenCover(isPresented: $isPlayed){
    VStack {
        VideoPlayer(player: avPlayer)
        .onAppear(){
            avPlayer.play()
        }
        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
    }
}
```

Comment: I am trying to do an init on avPlayer as firebasedb is at the state level, however I'm getting several errors. Since it's my first time using init, could you demonstrate how I can apply that? the variable I have on top is var firebasedb: movies and it is not initialized until the body begins

Comment: Next topic should be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65132038/how-to-manage-avplayer-state-in-swiftui